# Faster trace of product of two matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, built-in-symbols

I noticed that for the computation of the trace of a product of two matrices, using `Tr[Dot[A,B]]` is a little inefficient.  `Dot` is computing  *all* the elements of the matrix product, while `Tr` only needs the diagonal.

Is there a low-level, or fast implementation of trace-dot in *Mathematica*? (It needs to be able to work on matrices of mixed datatypes)

---

Look, I made a top-level implementation of trace-dot that is faster than `Trace[Dot[...]]`:

```
myTrDot[m1_,m2_]:=Total[MapThread[Dot, {m1, Transpose[m2]}]];

exMat1 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[1000]];
exMat2 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[1000]];

Tr[Dot[exMat1, exMat2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.020229 *)

myTrDot[exMat1, exMat2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.015503 *)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "It needs to be able to work on matrices of mixed datatypes"?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Entries of input matrices may be symbolic (such with head `Symbol`).

Comment: Then ulvi's `Flatten[m1].Flatten[Transpose[m2]]]` is probably the best you can achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myTrDot2 = 
 Compile[{{m1, _Real, 2}, {m2, _Real, 2}}, 
  Flatten[m1].Flatten[Transpose[m2]]]

exMat1 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[10000]];

exMat2 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[10000]];

Tr[Dot[exMat1, exMat2]]; // AbsoluteTiming

myTrDot[exMat1, exMat2]; // AbsoluteTiming

myTrDot2[exMat1, exMat2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {18.0692, Null}
>
> {1.64879, Null}
>
> {1.42026, Null}

Comment: ulvi, this compilation doesn't improve anything since `Flatten[m1].Flatten[Transpose[m2]]` is already vertorized.

Comment: Yes I realized that after posting, but doesn't hurt either...

Answer (score 4):

This seems a bit faster than your `myTrDot`:

```
m1 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2000]];
m2 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2000]];
cf = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}, {B, _Real, 2}}, 
         Module[{n = Length@A, Bt = Transpose@B}, Sum[A[[i]].Bt[[i]], {i, n}]]]

Tr[m1.m2]; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* 0.20 *)
myTrDot[m1, m2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.052 *)
cf[m1, m2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.028 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I also throw in my hat into the ring:

```
m1 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2000]];
m2 = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2000]];

a = Tr[m1.m2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = cf[m1, m2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = Total[Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, x.y,
       CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
       Parallelization -> True,
       RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
       ][m1, Transpose[m2]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.106
>
> 0.018
>
> 0.014
>
> True

Remark:

I am working on a Haswell quad core which seems to behave slightly different on such problems than more recent CPUs. So I am not sure if this method really performs better on other machines.