# Calculating the trace of the product of several matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I want to calculate the trace of something like

$\qquad\mathrm{Tr}(\Gamma_RG_d\Gamma_LG_d^\dagger)$

In order to optimise my code, I found something like this
[Faster trace of product of two matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169628/faster-trace-of-product-of-two-matrices),
which greatly reduces calculation time for trace.

My question is - Is it possible to generalize this somehow to the above case?
I tried looking at the Wikipedia with no luck

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product

Or is the most time efficient way just to say

$\qquad M_1 = \Gamma_rG_d \qquad M_2=\Gamma_LG_d^\dagger$

and then use the trick in the link and Wikipedia.

Comment: That depends on the matrices. If one or more of these matrices have low rank, then one could try to employ low-rank factorizations.

Answer (score 11):

If one or more of these matrices have low rank, then one could try to employ low-rank factorizations. Of course, *not all matrices have low rank*. I just try to point our that low rank can be exploited nicely if present.

In order to demonstrate the effect, here is an implementation of *Adaptive Cross Approximation (ACA)* (see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00005410) by Mario Bebendorf for more details on the algorithm). Because this implementation uses `` LinearAlgebra`BLAS`IAMAX `` which was introduced with version 11.2, this won't run on older versions of *Mathematica*.

```
Needs["LinearAlgebra`BLAS`"]

ClearAll[ACACompression];

Options[ACACompression] = {"MaxRank" -> 50, "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-4, 
   "StartingIndex" -> 1,
   "MaxPivotTrials" -> 100};

ACACompression::maxrank = "Warning: Computed factorization has maximal rank.";

ACACompression[A_?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := ACACompression[i \[Function] A[[i]], j \[Function] A[[All, j]], opts];

ACACompression[row_, column_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{maxrank, ϵ, u, v, k, ik, jk, uk, vk, test, norm2, δ, w, iter, uQ, uR, vQ, vR, rank, σ, m, n, eps, maxiter}, eps = $MachineEpsilon;
  maxiter = OptionValue["MaxPivotTrials"];
  maxrank = OptionValue["MaxRank"];
  ϵ = OptionValue["Tolerance"];
  k = 1;
  ik = OptionValue["StartingIndex"];
  vk = row[ik];
  m = Length[vk];
  v = ConstantArray[0., {maxrank, m}];
  jk = IAMAX[vk];
  v[[k]] = vk = vk/vk[[jk]];
  uk = column[jk];
  n = Length[uk];
  u = ConstantArray[0., {maxrank, n}];
  u[[k]] = uk;
  test = uk.uk vk.vk;
  norm2 = test;
  maxrank = Min[m, n, maxrank];
  While[test > ϵ^2 norm2 && k < maxrank,
   k++;
   ik = IAMAX[uk];
   vk = Subtract[row[ik], u[[;; k - 1, ik]].v[[;; k - 1]]];
   jk = IAMAX[vk];
   δ = vk[[jk]];
   If[Abs[δ] < eps, w = uk;
    δ = 0.;
    iter = 0;
    While[Abs[δ] < eps && iter < maxiter,
     iter++;
     w[[ik]] = 0.;
     ik = IAMAX[w];
     vk = Subtract[row[ik], u[[;; k - 1, ik]].v[[;; k - 1]]];
     jk = IAMAX[vk];
     δ = vk[[jk]];
     ];
    ];
   v[[k]] = vk = vk/δ;
   uk = Subtract[column[jk], v[[;; k - 1, jk]].u[[;; k - 1]]];
   u[[k]] = uk;
   test = uk.uk vk.vk;
   norm2 += test + Dot[u[[1 ;; k - 1]].uk, v[[1 ;; k - 1]].vk]
   ];
  If[k == OptionValue["MaxRank"], Message[ACACompression::maxrank];];
  {u[[1 ;; k]], v[[1 ;; k]]}]
```

Now let's consider the following setup. I assume that the matrix `G` has low rank; I ensure that by taking the squared distance matrix of a set of homogeneously distributed points. (I am well aware that $G$ in OP's example is probably thought of as a Gram matrix of an inner product and, as such,  positive definite so that it may be *not* of low rank. Still, `ΓR`, `ΓL` may be of low rank.)

```
n = 2000;
ΓR = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
ΓL = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
G = DistanceMatrix[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]]^2;
```

Now, let's compute the trace in the straight-forward way and compare the result and its timing to an ACA followed by a careful evaluation of the trace. Notice that the order in which the `Dot`-operations are performed is crucial here.

```
a = Tr[ΓR.G.ΓL.Transpose[G]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
First@RepeatedTiming[
  {u, v} = ACACompression[G, "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-6];
  b = Tr[(u.ΓR.Transpose[u]).(v.ΓL.Transpose[v])];
  ]

Abs[a - b]/Abs[a]
```

> 0.33
>
> 0.0033
>
> 4.71289*10^-16

Let's also check that the relative accuracy of ACA:

```
Max[Abs[Transpose[v].u - G]]/Max[Abs[G]]
```

> 3.33565*10^-16

**Edit**

Squared distance matrices in Euclidean space can actually factored explicitly:

```
FactoredSquaredDistanceMatrix[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] := {
  {x^2, x, ConstantArray[1., {Length[x]}]},
  {ConstantArray[1., {Length[y]}], -2. y, y^2}
  }
FactoredSquaredDistanceMatrix[x_?MatrixQ, y_?MatrixQ] := {
  Join[Partition[Total[x^2, {2}], 1], x, 
   ConstantArray[1., {Length[x], 1}], 2],
  Join[ConstantArray[1., {Length[y], 1}], -2. y, 
   Partition[Total[y^2, {2}], 1], 2]
  }
```

So the following can do the job *without ever forming* the squared distance matrix.

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  {u, v} = FactoredSquaredDistanceMatrix[x, x];
  c = Tr[(u.\[CapitalGamma]R.Transpose[
        u]).(v.\[CapitalGamma]L.Transpose[v])];
  ]
Abs[a - c]/Abs[a]
```

Comment: In fact, ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`IAMAX[]`` is available in older versions, just undocumented.