# Efficiently computing current flow betweenness centrality for graphs

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, linear-algebra, algorithm

**Definitions:**

Given a graph $G=(V,E),$ the current flow betweenness is a node-wise measure that captures the fraction of current through a given node with a unit source (s) sink (t) supply $b_{st}$ (1 unit of current inserted at node s, $b_{st}(s)=1$ and extracted at node t, $b_{st}(t)=-1,$ and $b_{st}(v)=0$ for $v\in V\setminus \{s,t\}$).

For a fixed s-t pair, the throughput $\tau$ of a node $v$ is given by:

$$
\tau_{st}(v)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-|b_{st}(v)|+\sum_{e\ni v}|I(e)|\right) \tag{1}
$$

where $b_{st}$ is the supply function defined above for the given $s,t$ pair, $I(e)$ is the current flowing through edge $e,$ and $e\ni v$ means all edges incident on vertex $v$ (i.e. $v$ is part of, irrespective of it being at tail or head of edge).

Now the current flow betweenness centrality of a node $v$ is simply a normalized sum over all its throughput for all possible supplied pairs $s,t,$ i.e.:

$$
c(v)=\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} \sum_{s,t\in V}\tau_{s,t}(v) \tag{2}.
$$

---

**My implementation of the current-flow betweenness centrality goes as follows:**

- Given a graph $G,$ I compute its incidence matrix `b`, corresponding Laplacian `lap`, and its inverse in `S` only once at the begining.
- Then I have a module which takes `n` ($n=|V|$), `b`, `S`, `conductances`, supply nodes `s,t` and returns the list of currents through edges for the given $s,t$ pair as supply.
- Then I have module that computes $\tau_{st}$ given in $(1),$ in which I use a piecewise function for supply $b_{st},$ and use `Total[]` to compute the sum in $(1).$
- Then I have a module that computes $c$ given in $(2),$ where I use a `Table` to compute $\tau$ of $v$ for all possible $s,t$ and then again use `Total` to sum them.
- Finally, to compute $c$ for all nodes I create a table that runs over all nodes and calls the module for $c.$

Actual implementation with a dummy random graph to showcase:

```
SeedRandom[123]
n = 15;
m = 20;
G = RandomGraph[{n, m}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
edges = EdgeList[G];

GDirected = 
 Graph[Range[n], Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, edges], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
conductances = ConstantArray[1., m];
b = -1.*Transpose[IncidenceMatrix[GDirected]];
lap = b\[Transpose].DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[conductances]].b;
a = SparseArray[ConstantArray[1., {1, n}]];
A = ArrayFlatten[{{lap, a\[Transpose]}, {a, 0.}}];
S = LinearSolve[A];
\[Epsilon] = 1. 10^-8;
s = 1;
t = 2;
```

Edge current module:

```
edgecurrents[ncount_, invertedkirch_, incid_, conducarr_, nodei_, 
   nodej_, threshold_] := 
  Module[{n = ncount, solver = invertedkirch, incidmat = incid, 
    G = conducarr, source = nodei, sink = nodej, eps = threshold},
   appliedcurr = 1.;
   J = SparseArray[{{source}, {sink}} -> {appliedcurr, -appliedcurr}, \
{n}, 0.];
   psi = solver[Join[J, {0.}]][[;; -2]];
   edgecurr = G incidmat.psi;
   (*define current threshold to take care of small values*)

   foundcurrents = Threshold[edgecurr, eps];
   Return[foundcurrents, Module];
   ];
```

$\tau$ module:

```
tau[edgels_, currls_, source_, sink_, vertex_] := 
  Module[{edges = edgels, iedges = currls, s = source, t = sink, 
    v = vertex},
   bst[u_, so_, to_] := Piecewise[{{1., u == so}, {-1., u == to}}, 0.];
   If[s == t,
    res = 0.,
    incidv = 
     Flatten[Position[
       edges, (v \[UndirectedEdge] _ | _ \[UndirectedEdge] v)]];
    If[incidv == {},
     inoutcurrs = 0.;
     ,
     inoutcurrs = Total[Abs[Part[iedges, incidv]]];
     ];
    res = 0.5*(-Abs[bst[v, s, t]] + inoutcurrs);
    ];
   Return[res, Module];
   ];
```

$c$ module:

```
currinbet[vcount_, edgels_, conduc_, vertex_, threshold_] := 
  Module[{n = vcount, edges = edgels, conducmat = conduc, v = vertex, 
    eps = threshold},
   taust = 
    Table[tau[edges, edgecurrents[n, S, b, conducmat, s, t, eps], s, 
      t, v], {s, n}, {t, n}];
   ccb = Total[taust, 2]/((n - 1)*(n - 2));
   Return[ccb, Module];
   ];
```

Example of currents for $s=1, t=2:$

```
edgecurrents[n, S, b, conductances, s, t, \[Epsilon]]
{0.640145, 0.359855, -0.0198915, -0.200723, -0.039783, -0.640145, \
-0.0994575, -0.0144665, 0., 0.0144665, -0.0198915, -0.0433996, \
0.0578662, -0.0144665, 0.359855, -0.359855, 0.101266, -0.0596745, 0., \
0.}
```

and computing the current-flow betweenness for all nodes:

```
vccb = Threshold[
  Table[currinbet[n, EdgeList[G], conductances, i, \[Epsilon]], {i, 1,
     n}], \[Epsilon]]

{0.182869, 0.403493, 0.268327, 0.052163, 0.253522, 0.240516, \
0.524532, 0.135177, 0., 0.208672, 0.275441, 0., 0., 0.282883, \
0.246786}
```

The obtained results are cross-checked with the existing [Python library Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.current_flow_betweenness_centrality.html) for computing $c$ and they are in perfect agreement. But sadly efficiency wise, I am doing terribly.

---

**Improved** notebook version after Henrik Schumacher's [suggestions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209065/52181) can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KZXuaeC7Z_vsQoUKzvVc-1dC-VJ3zi8f), with a working example.

---

**Questions:**

- I (think) have minimized the current through edge calculations since `S` is simply pre-computed, thanks to [Henrik Schumacher's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) approach [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193181/52181). However, I have the feeling I might be doing some things terribly inefficiently from then onward, as my routine slows down drastically for larger graphs. Is there anywhere I could be doing things much more efficiently?
- Is my module-based approach or use of tables also responsible for part of the slow-down?
- Maybe one line of optimization would be to cast $(1)$ and $(2)$ into linear-algebraic computations to speed them up, but I currently do not see how to do so.

(*Any general feedback for rendering the code more efficient is most welcome of course.*)

Comment: It is certainly not the bottle neck, but `Return[foundcurrents, Module];` is quite unorthodox and I do not know why you use it (I actually did not know that `Return` allows a second argument). Just writing `foundcurrents` (without semicolon) instead of `Return[foundcurrents, Module];` would be the _Mathematica_-way of returning a result of a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential bottleneck is

```
incidv = Flatten[Position[edges, (v \[UndirectedEdge] _ | _ \[UndirectedEdge] v)]]
```

as it involves (i) a search in the rather long list of edges and (ii) pattern matching, which both tend to be rather slow.

A quicker way will be to compute all these lists at once via

```
vertexedgeincidences = IncidenceMatrix[G]["AdjacencyLists"];
```

and to access the `v`-th one like this:

```
incidv = vertexedgeincidences[[v]]
```

The numbers

```
inoutcurrs = Total[Abs[Part[iedges, incidv]]];
```

can also all be computed at once for all `v`. This can be done with the help if the incidence matrix

```
B = IncidenceMatrix[G];
```

via

```
B.Abs[iedges]
```

As a general suggestion: Whenever you find yourself evaluating a `Sum` or  `Total` of something, try to rephrase it into `Dot`-products of vectors, matrices, etc.

Comment: Hi Henrik, sorry for the late reply, didn't notice how time went by... Really helpful recommendations, incorporating them reduced the absolutetiming by a third so far! I also call the current calculator function half as often as the matrix is symmetric, so now my updates sub-modules are: `tau[s_, t_, v_, inoutcurrs_] :=
    With[{bst = Piecewise[{{1., v == s}, {-1., v == t}}, 0.]}, res = 0.5*(-Abs[bst] + inoutcurrs[[v]])];` and `currinbet` is (...)

Comment: (...) I edited the post and added a link to the latest version (a notebook with a working example), which is much simpler to show what I have now instead of pasting code again. Do you reckon my main bottleneck lies in the current calculation still? (despite being cut in half), thanks again for all your feedback.